# How to select unique rows from one to many relationed tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select, unique

As MySQL-Noob I am struggeling to solve the following task: Assuming 3 tables: `location` `groceries` and `person` with the following properties:

1. Every table has a primary autoincremented integer id and a varchar column.
2. The entrys in the tables are all unique.
3. Every entry in `groceries` has a foreign key of an entry in `person`.
4. It is possible that more then one entry from `groceries` share the same foreign key.
5. (3) and (4) apply to `person` and `location`, too

So we have a many to one to many relation. How can I select every triple `(groceries_product, person_name, location_name)` where `person_name` does not occur more then once?

Example:

```
tables:  groceries                  | person      | location
------------------------------------ ------------- -------------------------
columns: id  product      person_id | id  name    | id  name  person_id
------------------------------------ ------------- -------------------------
         1   hamburger    1         | 1   Peter   | 1   home  1
         2   cheeseburger 1         | 2   Tom     | 2   work  1
         3   carot        1         |             | 3   zoo   2 
         4   potatoe      1         |             |
         5   mango        2         |             |
```

All the triples you can create in which `Peter` occures are irrelevant. I want only triples like (mango, Tom, zoo), because Tom does occure only once in all possibilities. I hope my question ist understandable. :-)

Comment: Would be nice if you gave these tables names and column names. 9 out of 10 times, reducing the real problem to a trivial fake problem when asking a question, you don't get the right answer to the real problem.

Comment: @Dan Grossman: I tryed to improve the question. Is this better?

Comment: @Dan Grossman. I did. I thought you suggested to alter the question anyway for better readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to do a subselect to get your result:

```
SELECT groceries.product, person.name, location.name
FROM person
LEFT JOIN groceries ON person.id = groceries.person_id
LEFT JOIN location ON person.id = location.person_id
WHERE person.id
IN (
SELECT person.id
FROM person
LEFT JOIN groceries ON person.id = groceries.person_id
LEFT JOIN location ON person.id = location.person_id
GROUP BY person.id
HAVING count( person.id ) =1
)
```

Comment: May I ask you: First you join (cartesian product) the tables and generate only the rows whose person entry does occure only once. That means if a name of a person occures in two rows of the cartesian product you throw them both away. Then you join again and select only the rows, whose person entry is available in the first set. Did I understand your query right?

Comment: Yes, you got it. The inner select gives the person_ids which occure only once in an cartesian product over all three tables. I'm always using left joins for such joins. I don't know exactly why - I think it's a (bad) habit of me. Then in the outer select I choose the needed tables and columns for output and filter by the person_ids of the inner select.

Comment: It seems to work, although it takes some time. :-) Thank you very much for your effort!

Comment: Then it would be nice to mark my answer as the correct one. :) To optimize your database/selects simply put an EXPLAIN in front of your select statement and analyse the results. If there are any joins which show an "ALL" in column "type" then there is much performance to gain by inserting an index. For your table structure it makes sense to add an index to all foreign key columns (if not yet done) and you will see, the select will run really fast.

Answer (score -1):

```
select l.name, m.name, r.name
from `left` l
left join middle m on m.id = l.middle_id
left join `right` r on m.id = r.middle_id;
```

Comment: This does not satisfy the requirements ("where `middle_entry` does not occur more then once") or even join the tables together correctly.

Comment: `on r.id = r.middle_id`... no, it doesn't, you never join the middle and right tables.