# SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I can't get this sql query right...

I want the top 5 latest comments from `tblComment`. The problem is that I get more then one comment with the same `ProductID`. I don't want that.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5
   tblProduct.ProductID, 
   tblProduct.ProductName, 
   tblComment.DateAdded
FROM   
    tblComment 
INNER JOIN 
    tblProduct ON tblProduct.ProductID = tblComment.ProductID
ORDER BY 
    tblComment.DateAdded DESC
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So, there are five different Products, and you want the most recent comment for each product?

Comment: This is a one-to-many join. You WILL get many rows :) Here look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922675/how-to-select-unique-rows-from-one-to-many-relationed-tables-in-mysql

Comment: There are hundreds of products and I want the top 5 products that most recently had a comment added to it. Even if one product had the latest five comments I dont want that product five times as a result. I want five diffrent products.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your comment table has an id field try this:

```
SELECT TOP 5

tblProduct.ProductID, 
tblProduct.ProductName, 
tblComment.DateAdded

FROM   tblComment 
JOIN   tblProduct ON tblProduct.ProductID = tblComment.ProductID
JOIN   (Select ProductID, max(id) as maxid From tblComment Group By ProductId) t on tblComment.id = t.maxid 

ORDER BY tblComment.DateAdded DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to sub select - use the following example to suit your needs.

```
SELECT TOP 5 tblProduct.ProductID, 
          tblProduct.ProductName, 
          tblComment.DateAdded
FROM   tblComment INNER JOIN
    tblProduct ON tblProduct.ProductID = tblComment.ProductID
    and tblProduct.ProductID 
      IN (
            SELECT tblProduct.ProductID 
            FROM tblComment 
                   INNER JOIN tblProduct ON tblProduct.ProductID = tblComment.ProductID
            GROUP BY tblProduct.ProductID 
            HAVING count( tblProduct.ProductID  ) =1
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

Products ranked by time of latest comment.

This approach uses a CTE and and a rank function. This query is small but on larger queries these functions can make things more organized and readable.

```
with lastComment as (
  select c.productID, max(DateAdded) DateAdded, 
    row_number() over(order by max(dateAdded)) rank
  from tblComment c
  group by c.productID

)

SELECT
   tblProduct.ProductID, 
   tblProduct.ProductName, 
   tblComment.DateAdded
FROM   
    tblProduct 
    join lastComment ON tblProduct.ProductID = lastCommnet.ProductID
WHERE
   lastComment.rank >= 5
ORDER BY lastComment.rank
```